# set env variable in Kubernetes clusters

Tags: bash, kubernetes, google-cloud-storage, sh

I am new to Kubernetes.

I found some errors while using google-cloud-storage.

The problem is,
when I specify GCLOUD_PRIVATE_KEY directly in .yaml file,
I work nicely.

```
 - name: GCLOUD_PRIVATE_KEY
   value: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n(...)\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
```

However, when I inject the variable to cluster.

AT terminal

```
kubectl create secret generic gcloud-private-key --from-literal=GCLOUD_PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n(...)\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
```

AT .yaml

```
- name: GCLOUD_PRIVATE_KEY
  valueFrom: 
    secretKeyRef:
       name: gcloud-private-key
       key: GCLOUD_PRIVATE_KEY
```

The error related to key occurs.
I even tried for escape notation just in case,

AT terminal

```
kubectl create secret generic gcloud-private-key --from-literal=GCLOUD_PRIVATE_KEY='"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n(...)\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"'
```

However, it doesn't work as well! Can you let me know how I can fix it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kubectl create secret generic gcloud-private-key --from-literal=GCLOUD_PRIVATE_KEY='"...\n...`

'\n', '"' are invalid character for TLS key when create from literal. You can load the key directly from the original file as-is:

`kubectl create secret generic gcloud-private-key --from-literal GCLOUD_PRIVATE_KEY="$(cat <file>)"`

Comment: Thank a lot!! you save me from this hell. By the way, I still don't understand how it goes. When I generate the txt file, the double quote is gone(from my editor). However, whenever, I add to .yaml the value. I need to specify "" for the value. So does .txt file treat automatically wraped with  "" when they import to cluster??

Answer (score 0):

Based on the hint what gohm'c gives, I solved this problem.

AT terminal

```
echo -n  "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n(...)\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n" > ./gcloud-private-key.txt

kubectl create secret generic gcloud-private-key --from-file=GCLOUD_PRIVATE_KEY=./gcloud-private-key.txt
```

AT .yaml

```
- name: GCLOUD_PRIVATE_KEY
  valueFrom: 
    secretKeyRef:
       name: gcloud-private-key
       key: GCLOUD_PRIVATE_KEY
```